# How to read excel sheet using perl script with simple check condition

Tags: perl

Im new bee to perl trying to read excel sheet with simple condition..

problem is reading all records and checking whether b columns has "Always null" string if yes then display output from Column "C"

Example : For Always Null condtion

Expected output : a,b,c,f,g

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ws = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel
                ->new()
                ->parse('yourfile.xls')
                ->worksheet(0);

my ($i, $r_max) = $ws->row_range;

my ($cell_B, $cell_C);

while ($i <= $r_max) {
    $cell_B = $ws->get_cell($i,1);
    $cell_C = $ws->get_cell($i,2);

    say $cell_C->value 
        if $cell_B 
            and $cell_C 
            and $cell_B->value eq 'Always null';
} continue { $i++ }
```